# <Materials xmlns='x'> was not expected

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, hierarchical-data, xml-deserialization

I am attempting to deserialize a hierarchical xml file with following method

```
    public static T Deserialize<T>(this string serializedObj) where T : class
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        T result;

        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(serializedObj))
            result = xs.Deserialize(reader) as T;

        return result;
    }
```

But he keeps falling over the fact that there is a reference to the schema in the xml file and I have no clue what is wrong. I tried to deserialize into an object and even there he keeps on failing.

The function that tries to deserialize the xml is the following

```
    public static void RecieveAndSaveXml(string fullPath, string basePath, string fileName)
    {
        if (File.Exists(fullPath))
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fullPath);
            string xmlString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Material material = xmlString.Deserialize<Material>();

            //Conversion to dataobject goes here

            reader.Close();
        }
    }
```

The class that I am trying to deserialize to

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Material")]
public class Material
{
    public Material() { }

    [XmlAttribute("MatNr")]
    public string MatNr { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("MatDescrEN")]
    public string MatDescrEN { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("MatDescrNL")]
    public string MatDescrNL { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("MatDescrFR")]
    public string MatDescrFR { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("OldMatNr")]
    public string OldMatNr { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("UoM")]
    public string UoM { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("MatGroupCode")]
    public string MatGroupCode { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Extract")]
    public decimal Extract { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("AdditionalData"), XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "AddDataRecord", Type = typeof(AddDataRecord))]
    public AddDataRecord[] AdditionalData { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("PlantData"), XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "PlantDataRecord", Type = typeof(PlantDataRecord))]
    public PlantDataRecord[] PlantData { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("AddDataRecord")]
public class AddDataRecord
{
    [XmlAttribute("UoMDenom")]
    public int UoMDenom { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("UoMAlt")]
    public string UoMAlt { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("UoMNum")]
    public int UoMNum { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("UoMBase")]
    public string UoMBase { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("PlantDataRecord")]
public class PlantDataRecord
{
    [XmlAttribute("Plant")]
    public string Plant { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Recipient")]
    public string Recipient { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

}

And the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Materials xmlns:ns0="www.foo.be/foo/">
<Material>
    <MatNr>000000000050165478</MatNr>
    <MatDescrEN>KEG CAP GREEN PR JUP NA 1/2008</MatDescrEN>
    <MatDescrNL></MatDescrNL>
    <MatDescrFR></MatDescrFR>
    <OldMatNr>000000000000216505</OldMatNr>
    <UoM>PCE</UoM>
    <MatGroupCode>020506</MatGroupCode>
    <Extract></Extract>
    <AdditionalData>
        <AddDataRecord>
            <UoMDenom>1</UoMDenom>
            <UoMAlt>PCE</UoMAlt>
            <UoMNum>1</UoMNum>
            <UoMBase>PCE</UoMBase>
        </AddDataRecord>
    </AdditionalData>
    <PlantData>
        <PlantDataRecord>
            <Plant>BE01</Plant>
            <Recipient></Recipient>
            <Status>99</Status>
        </PlantDataRecord>
    </PlantData>
</Material>
</ns0:Materials>
```

So what I have tried is

- Putting the nested classes in comment
- Deserializing to object
- Changing the list types
- Changed annotations from XmlAttribute to XmlArray with XmlArrayItem
- Added XmlRootItems

So I have no idea what to try next so thats why I'm posting here. Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all your xml is not well-formed, element `ns0:Materials` is not closed; second of all - that element suggests some kind of a list of `Material`, which you're trying to deserialize as a single instance - could you clarify?

Comment: For some reason he didn't take my closing tag in the post that was weird. And can't u deserialize an hierarchical xml?

Comment: of course you can; I'm just point that your XML seems to describe the following structure: `<Materials><Material1/><Material2/><Material.../></Materials>` and you're trying to deserialize this as a single object. Is this intended? If not - is the `<ns0:Materials>` element necessary? You can work around it if it is, but it seems redundant if it's just a single `Material` each time.

Comment: Ah okay , yes this is intended for the case when there are more materials used at one instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your classes when compared to the XML file provided:

- All properties are `elements` in the sample xml, yet they have `XmlAttribute` in your C# classes
- You have a non-nullable decimal value (`Extract`), for which the corresponding xml element is empty. If this is a valid case, you need to handle this somehow.
- Your xml indicates a collection of `Material`s, but you're trying to deserialize it as a single instance of `Material`.

Updated code:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Material")]
public class Material
{
    public Material() { }

    [XmlElement("MatNr")]
    public string MatNr { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("MatDescrEN")]
    public string MatDescrEN { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("MatDescrNL")]
    public string MatDescrNL { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("MatDescrFR")]
    public string MatDescrFR { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("OldMatNr")]
    public string OldMatNr { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("UoM")]
    public string UoM { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("MatGroupCode")]
    public string MatGroupCode { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Extract")]
    public String ExtractString { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public decimal Extract
    {
        get { return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.ExtractString) ? 0M : decimal.Parse(this.ExtractString); }
        set { this.ExtractString = this.Extract.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }
    }
    [XmlArray("AdditionalData"), XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "AddDataRecord", Type = typeof(AddDataRecord))]
    public AddDataRecord[] AdditionalData { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("PlantData"), XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "PlantDataRecord", Type = typeof(PlantDataRecord))]
    public PlantDataRecord[] PlantData { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("AddDataRecord")]
public class AddDataRecord
{
    [XmlElement("UoMDenom")]
    public int UoMDenom { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("UoMAlt")]
    public string UoMAlt { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("UoMNum")]
    public int UoMNum { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("UoMBase")]
    public string UoMBase { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("PlantDataRecord")]
public class PlantDataRecord
{
    [XmlElement("Plant")]
    public string Plant { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Recipient")]
    public string Recipient { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("Materials", Namespace = "www.foo.be/foo/")]
[Serializable]
public class MaterialCollection
{
   [XmlElement("Material", Namespace="")]
   public List<Material> Materials { get; set; }
}
```

You'd then need to use

```
MaterialCollection materials = xmlString.Deserialize<MaterialCollection>();
```

Answer (score 1):

an alternative to writing the class(es) manually would be to generate the class file using the `xsd.exe` tool.

The latest versions of `Visual Studio` don't include it anymore however, so you'll have to get it [here](http://juliankay.com/development/download-xsd-exe/).

Assuming your xml file is under c:\ and you can call `xsd.exe` from there, you can generate a `materials.cs` file in the following manner:

```
c:\>xsd materials.xml
```

followed by

```
c:\>xsd materials.xsd /classes
```